# SharePoint add shortcut to OneDrive: Is it possible to maintain custom metadata?

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I'm attempting to add a shortcut from a SharePoint library to my OneDrive. There are many elements (files, folders, document sets) in the SharePoint library that have visible custom metadata in the browser view, but they don't seem to persist upon syncing with my local OneDrive. Is it possible to maintain this custom library metadata in OneDrive?

I've tried creating a file in my local OneDrive however there doesn't seem to be an option to create custom metadata/details and the SharePoint sync appears to only display the file details that are natively supported by Windows.